# How to use MYSQL GROUP BY SUM with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

Basically the question is how to **get the sum from #hours**, groupping by #id, #code, #semester, #year columns from this

```
   id, hours, code, semester, year
  165,     6,    3,        1, 2012
  166,     6,   16,        1, 2012
  460,     8,   14,        2, 2012
  461,     8,   16,        2, 2012
  462,    15,   16,        2, 2013
  463,     6,    1,        2, 2013

   id, hours, code, semester, year, sum
  165,     6,    3,        1, 2012, **6**
  166,     6,   16,        1, 2012, **6**
  460,     8,   14,        2, 2012, **8**
  461,     8,   16,        2, 2012, **23**
  462,    15,   16,        2, 2012, **23**
  463,     6,    1,        2, 2013, **6**
```

I have tried a lot with GROUP BY, GROUP BY CONCAT, etc, but no success.

I want to group by all these columns in each row

Comment: hours ad sum of hours in one line makes no sence.

Comment: I can't spot the difference between the first box and the second box at all.

Comment: SO does not support td markup

Comment: That edit did not help me at all.

Comment: `SELECT id,hours,code,semester,year,'?' mysum FROM my_table`

Comment: @Strawberry, but i want to group by all these columns in each row.

Comment: My comment provides the result requested in the question. If you want a different result, ask a different question.

Comment: I have edited the question to a more complete question.

Comment: I just don't understand, @Marco all you did was add another column with a question mark. Can you show some sample data and expected results?

Comment: Example:
ID 10, YEAR 2012, SEMESTER 2, CODE 2, HOURS 20, SUM 33 
ID 11, YEAR 2012, SEMESTER 2, CODE 2, HOURS 13, SUM 33 
ID 12, YEAR 2013, SEMESTER 1, CODE 2, HOURS 8, SUM 18
ID 13, YEAR 2013, SEMESTER 1, CODE 2, HOURS 10, SUM 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select id, code, semester, year, sum(hours) from `table` group by id,code,semester, year
```

Comment: Jens, I have tried this, but i get the MYSQL error "Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s).

Comment: @marco is hours a column of your table?

Comment: yes, it is a column from my table, as stated in the table.

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain the code. If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner is more likely to learn something!

Comment: @marco You change `table` with your table name?

Comment: sure i changed...  :(

Comment: @Marco what type is your column hours?

Comment: The type of column is INTEGER (INT).

Comment: 17:39:52 SELECT      f.numero_folha,     SUM(f.horasAtividade) AS soma,     f.codigoAtividadeProcessosGerenciais,     f.semestre,     f.ano FROM     folha f GROUP BY (f.numero_folha, f.codigoAtividadeProcessosGerenciais, f.semestre, f.ano) LIMIT 0, 1000 Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s) 0.000 sec

Comment: The name columns are different because it is in portuguese, so i changed the names to "english names".

Comment: @Marco remove the parens around your group by statement.

Comment: horasAtividade = hours
numero_folha = id
soma = sum
codigoatividadeprocessosgerenciais = code
semestre = semester
ano = year

Comment: @McAdam331 Wow Adam, i removed and i get no more error, but the results are not correct... the sum column is equal to hours columns in each row.

Comment: That's to be expected. You don't have any solid groups, there's only one row for each pairing of id, code, semester, year, so it's only going to sum that single row.

Comment: Any idea for this, Adam?

Comment: @Marco can you add the table creation statement and some sample data?

Comment: Example: ID 10, YEAR 2012, SEMESTER 2, CODE 2, HOURS 20, SUM 33

Comment: ID 11, YEAR 2012, SEMESTER 2, CODE 2, HOURS 13, SUM 33

Comment: ID is auto_increment, primary key.

Comment: I have tried with this creation statement `create table x (ID int, YEAR int ,SEMESTER int, CODE int, HOURS int, SUM int);` and therefore my `select`works fine.

Comment: @Jens there is no SUM column in my table... i generate the SUM from SELECT SUM(hours)

Comment: Marco I have removed this column and it works fine too.

Comment: @Jens I noted that your select have only the #sum column... I also want to select the #hours column... maybe this be the difference between my "select" and yours.

Answer (score 0):

to sum a values of a column you can use `SUM()` function of MYSQL and you can return it as on of fields like this for example the field of sum in this query would be total_hours

```
SELECT id,hours,code,semester,year, SUM(hours) AS total_hours
FROM table_name
GROUP BY  id,code,semester, year
```

Comment: I have tried this, but i get the MYSQL error "Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s).

Comment: @Marco It is impossible to generate that error from this query. Perhaps there's something you're not telling us.